# Dynamic mouseenter

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, mouseover, onmouseover

I appended a few divs with inside img tags. Every tag has own unique id = "theImg"+i where "i" is number. I want to mouseover on specific img and show the content of span (which also have specific id with number). Here is my code so far but not working.

```
var j;  
document.onmouseover = function(r) {
    console.log(r.target.id);
    j = r.target.id;
}

$(document).on({
    mouseover: function(e){
     $("span").show();
    },
    mouseleave: function(e){
     $("span").hide();
    }
}, "img#"+j);
```

Comment: Are you saying that for each "theImg"+i there is a corresponding span with id "theSpan"+i (same number for both)?

Comment: Yes correct, i appended it in loop iteration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a span after every `img`, maybe it's a good idea to not use JavaScript at all? ;-)

You could use `:hover` pseudoclass in CSS, making your thing always work reliably.

Consider the following example:

```css
img + span {
  display: none;
}
img:hover + span {
  display: block;
}

/*/ Optional styles /*/
div {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
div img + span {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  background: #27ae60;
  border: solid 1px #2ecc71;
  border-radius: 50px;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 1em;
  width: 80%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -43%;
  padding: 2% 3%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://placehold.it/400x200">
  <span>This is an image of a gray rectangle!</span>
</div>

<div>
  <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200">
  <span>This is an image of a gray square!</span>
</div>

<div>
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/g/400/200">
  <span>This is an image of a cute kitten inside a rectangle!</span>
</div>

<div>
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/g/200/200">
  <span>This is an image of even cuter kitten inside a square!</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution doesn't seems work for me. I think becouse my divs are appended after the page load here is my code please check the full version of applcation for better solution. Thanks. http://codepen.io/Felnyr/pen/mRVvPj?editors=1011

Comment: Ok i think i found a solution. Actually your answer satisfy me. Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad it works! The thing with CSS is... it doesn't matter _when_ you add elements to document, as long as they follow defined CSS selectors. `img + span` says _"any `span` element that is in the document *exactly* after any `img` element"_. You can of course make it more specific, defining parents with certain #IDs or .classes. If you have any more questions, don't hesitate to ask!

Answer (score 0):

So the issue is that you are trying to set your handler on a dynamic selector ("img#"+j) but this will not work. For one thing, that equation will be evaluated only once, on page load, when j is undefined.

So you want to do this instead:

1. target only img tags for your mouse over... Better yet, give your special images all the same css class so you can attach the event handlers only to those. That will be more efficient.
2. When an image is moused over or out of, grab it's id attribute, extract the number from it, then use that to build a selector for the appropriate span to show.

   var get_span_from_image = function(image) {
       var image_id = image.attr("id");
       var matches = image_id.match(/theImg(\d+)/);
       if(matches) return $("theSpan" + matches[1]);
       return $(); // nothing found, return an empty jQuery selection
   };
   $("img").hover(
       function() { // mouse over
           get_span_from_image($(this)).show();
       },
       function() { // mouse out
           get_span_from_image($(this)).hide();
       }
   );

*Note: There are better ways to "link" two nodes together, but this is just to answer your question with the current structure you have.*

**UPDATE: Some ideas to link two nodes together**

So instead of trying to extract a number from an id attribute, a better way would be to tell either one of the image or span about it's sibling. You could output your html like this, for instance:

```
<img id="theImg1" data-target="theSpan1" class="hoverable" src="..."/>
....
<span id="theSpan1">...</span>
```

Of course now your ideas could be anything - you don't have to use numbered values or anything.

Then your hover code becomes quite simply:

```
var get_span_from_image = function(image) {
    var span_id = image.data("target");
    return $("#" + span_id);
};
$("img").hover(
    function() { // mouse over
        get_span_from_image($(this)).show();
    },
    function() { // mouse out
        get_span_from_image($(this)).hide();
    }
);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If you know better way don't hesitate to share it here :)